# For loops to count minute in a datetime column and appending to second

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime, for-loop

I have a dataframe and I need add second unit to datetime column. I tried various resampling method, but I couldn't!!! Here is the sample of my data.

$

```html
id  date_time
73430677    4:24:00
73430688    4:24:00
73430703    4:24:00
73430713    4:24:00
73430718    4:24:00
73430728    4:24:00
73430771    4:25:00
73430818    4:25:00
73430864    4:25:00
73430904    4:25:00
73430942    4:25:00
73430993    4:25:00
```

How I can count the similar minutes then according their number generate the second interval uinte. For instance, 4:24:00 repeated six times then data were gathered every 10 seconds.

I am looking for a solution to count the similar minutes then by calculating data gathering time interval(60/(number of repetition of minutes)) in second unit, appends second values to datetime column.

[image: Target datetime column]

I welcome to any practical solution!!!!

Comment: Could you include the input data as a code segment, instead of a picture, please? I think it could be done with a `groupby` and custom resampler.

Comment: @VirtualScooter I did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- modified your sample data so there is a group of 6 and a group of 5
- `groupby().transform()` to calculate number of seconds to be added to time
- add the number of seconds
- cleanup the temp column **secs**

```
from pathlib import Path
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""id  date_time
73430677    4:24:00
73430688    4:24:00
73430703    4:24:00
73430713    4:24:00
73430718    4:24:00
73430728    4:24:00
73430771    4:25:00
73430818    4:25:00
73430904    4:25:00
73430942    4:25:00
73430993    4:25:00"""), sep="\s+")

# add a dummy column
df["x"] = 1
f = Path.cwd().joinpath("SO_seconds.csv")
df.to_csv(f)

# read from a file
df = pd.read_csv(f)
df.date_time = pd.to_datetime(df.date_time)
# do the actual requirement
df = (df.assign(secs=df.groupby("date_time")["id"].transform(lambda s: [((i+1)/len(s))*60 for i,v in enumerate(s)]),
         date_time=lambda dfa: dfa.apply(lambda r: r.date_time + pd.Timedelta(seconds=r.secs), axis=1).dt.time)
 .drop(columns=["secs"])
)
```

|  | id | date_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 73430677 | 04:24:10 |
| 1 | 73430688 | 04:24:20 |
| 2 | 73430703 | 04:24:30 |
| 3 | 73430713 | 04:24:40 |
| 4 | 73430718 | 04:24:50 |
| 5 | 73430728 | 04:25:00 |
| 6 | 73430771 | 04:25:12 |
| 7 | 73430818 | 04:25:24 |
| 8 | 73430904 | 04:25:36 |
| 9 | 73430942 | 04:25:48 |
| 10 | 73430993 | 04:26:00 |

Comment: could you please let me know how I can perform your code on a csv file which contains many columns and saved in a directory. Actually, I searched but I couldn't find helpful instruction.

Comment: just replace `read_csv()` with version. that loads your file and specify a column that `groupby()` operates on,  e.g. `df.groupby("date_time")["id"].transform(lambda s: [((i+1)/len(s))*60 for i,v in enumerate(s)])` if **id** is a column in your DF

Comment: @RayRaymond I was not sure I understand your mean, but anyway I spent my efforts to execute your code. In fact, I read my csv file using df=pd.read.csv('d:/101.csv') then I try to rewrite your code pd.df(io.StringIO("""id  date_time""")) but it returned error that "module 'pandas' has no attribute 'df'". Unfortunately, I am not experienced programmer and need more description if it is possible for you not only for first command but also for performing groupby.

Comment: I've updated - I used a shortcut to take sample data you posted into question, so I had no need to create a file on disk,  just used a memory buffer.  Now you can see I have written it to disk and read it from disk.  Plus added column reference I noted.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know how I can thank you for your big help. I performed your code. Thanks again, I appreciate your help. Just, the number of my time record is around 28000. Then I got forced to copy all records in the jupyter lab cell to perform io.StringIO. Is there any way to perform this io.StringIO command on date column in a csv file without copying the records in the cell?

Comment: I thought I made it clear.... `io.StringIO()` is not required in the solution at all.  It's just convenient for me to get your sample data into a dataframe.  There is only one functional line of code. just load your CSV and run the functional code.  Basic coding 101,  a) obtain your data. b) run analytics. c) distribute results.  I've provided for b). io.StringIO is just a) which would be substituted with your data and data flow

Comment: Thanks thanks thanks. Honestly, I have worked on this issue since yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `.groupby` method and applying a custom function, we get the following code. I removed one row from your dataframe, to demonstrate difference in seconds increments:

```
import io
import datetime
import pandas as pd

resec_last = None
extra_secs = None
num_secs = None
dfg = None

def resec(row):
    global resec_last, extra_secs, num_secs, dfg
    new_blk = resec_last is None or row.date_time != resec_last
    if new_blk:
        resec_last = row.date_time
        cnt = dfg.loc[row.date_time].id
        extra_secs = datetime.timedelta(seconds=60/cnt)
        num_secs = 1
    else:
        row.date_time += num_secs * extra_secs
        num_secs += 1
    return row

csv_str = '''\
id  date_time
73430677    4:24:00
73430688    4:24:00
73430703    4:24:00
73430713    4:24:00
73430718    4:24:00
73430728    4:24:00
73430771    4:25:00
73430818    4:25:00
73430864    4:25:00
73430904    4:25:00
73430942    4:25:00
'''
# 73430993    4:25:00

with io.StringIO(initial_value=csv_str) as f:
    df = pd.read_csv(f, sep='\s+')
df.date_time = pd.to_datetime(df.date_time)
dfg = df.groupby('date_time').count()
df2 = df.apply(resec, axis=1, result_type='broadcast')
print(df2)
```

Output

```
          id           date_time
0   73430677 2021-02-27 04:24:00
1   73430688 2021-02-27 04:24:10
2   73430703 2021-02-27 04:24:20
3   73430713 2021-02-27 04:24:30
4   73430718 2021-02-27 04:24:40
5   73430728 2021-02-27 04:24:50
6   73430771 2021-02-27 04:25:00
7   73430818 2021-02-27 04:25:12
8   73430864 2021-02-27 04:25:24
9   73430904 2021-02-27 04:25:36
10  73430942 2021-02-27 04:25:48
```